# Using char in Visual C++ for fixed strings

Tags: c, visual-studio

I am writing an API and I need to make a routine available to read the version of the API.

For example,

```
#define APIVERSION "API Version 0.0"
```

I need to define the routine that reads it as:

```
uint8_t getAPIVersion (const char **);
```

The `char` could be signed or unsigned. But is there a definition in stdint.h equivalent to the uint8_t for the unsigned char? Can someone clarify?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From stdint.h...

```
typedef unsigned char   uint8_t;
```

Is your code not working as you expected?

Answer (score 0):

`unsigned char` is what you are looking, which also got `typedef` as `uint8_t` in `stdint.h`

Few older versions of `visual studio` does not have `stdint.h`. So it might be useful to typedef your own type, for example

```
typedef unsigned char uchar_t;
```

Comment: I have Visual Studio Premium 2013, however, this type is undefined in the stdint.h like you mentioned!

Comment: May be typedeffing yourself is better approach, in that case